Does minimal polynomial being separable mod $\mathfrak p$ imply that $p$ does not divide $\left|\mathcal O_L / \mathcal O_K[\alpha]\right|$?
Let $L/K$ be a Galois extension of number fields, where $L=K(\alpha)$ for some algebraic integer $\alpha\in\mathcal O_L$. Let $f(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$. Let $\mathfrak p$ be a prime (ideal) in $\mathcal O_K$ lying over $p\in \Bbb Z$.

Question: If $f(x)$ is separable mod $\mathfrak p$, does it follow that $p$ does not divide the index $\left|\mathcal O_L / \mathcal O_K[\alpha]\right|$?

Context: I ask because there are two closely related theorems describing the prime decomposition of $\mathfrak p$ in terms of the irreducible factors of $f(x)$ mod $\mathfrak p$: Proposition 5.11 in Cox's Primes of the Form $x^2+ny^2$, and Theorem 27 in Marcus's Number Fields. Cox's version looks like a special case of Marcus's, since Cox assumes that the extension is Galois and that $f$ is separable mod $\mathfrak p$, which Marcus doesn't. Cox even refers to Marcus theorem with "[...] is a general fact that holds for arbitrary finite extensions", but Cox also presents a simplified proof in the Galois, separable case as an exercise.  On the other hand, Marcus includes $p \nmid \left|\mathcal O_L / \mathcal O_K[\alpha]\right|$ as a necessary assumption. So do Cox's assumptions imply Marcus', or are there cases where Cox's version is stronger?

Attempts and ideas: Let's consider a family of examples. Let $K=\Bbb Q$ and $\alpha = k\sqrt m$ with $k,m\in\Bbb Z$ and $m$ squarefree $\ne0,1$. Then $L=\Bbb Q(\sqrt m)$ and $\mathcal O_L$ is $\Bbb Z[\sqrt m]$ or $\Bbb Z\left[\frac{1+\sqrt m}2\right]$ depending on $m$. We find:
$$
|\mathcal O_L / \Bbb Z[k\sqrt m]| = \begin{cases} 2|k| & m\equiv 1 \pmod 4 \\ |k| & \textrm{otherwise}\end{cases}.
$$
(I hope I didn't make a mistake in the calculation!) We also have $f(x) = x^2 \pm k^2m$, where the sign depends on the sign of $k$. Now, if $p$ divides $|\mathcal O_L / \Bbb Z[k\sqrt m]|$, there are two cases:
$$\begin{split}
p\mid k&: f(x) \equiv x^2 \pmod p,
\\
p=2\textrm{ and $k,m$ both odd}&: f(x) \equiv x^2 + 1 \equiv (x+1)^2 \pmod 2.
\end{split}$$
In both cases, $f$ is seen to be inseparable, as expected. In the first case, the constant term is $0$, and one might hope that this generalizes, but the second case shows that it doesn't (at least not always). The constant term is interesting since it is $\pm N_{L/K}(\alpha)$, so it could be related to divisibility.
My other ideas are in the direction of counting the possible number of roots of $f(x)$ and reaching some contradiction from that (vaguely: some polynomial has $n<p$ roots over a field, so $p\nmid n$). In particular $f$ separable implies that $f$ has exactly $|L/K|$ distinct roots in some extension of the quotient field $K/\mathfrak p$ (right?). But I'm not even sure which field this would be - some quotient of $\mathcal O_L$? And then I would compare this to some tower of indices/degrees, but only end up confusing myself, and I'm also especially rusty when it comes to the properties of separable polynomials in general.
Or maybe one would need to leverage the Galois assumption and consider the permutation of primes or use that ramification indices and inertial degrees are uniform. I don't know.

Suppose that there exists another prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}’$ of $\mathcal{O}_K$ above $p$, and $u \in \mathfrak{p}’ \backslash ((\mathfrak{p}’)^2\cup \mathfrak{p})$. Then $\alpha’ := u\alpha$ satisfies the same assumptions, but $\mathfrak{p}’$ is in the support of the (finite torsion) $\mathcal{O}_K$-module $\mathcal{O}_L/\mathcal{O}_K[\alpha’]$, hence $p \mid |\mathcal{O}_L/\mathcal{O}_K[\alpha’]|$.
I think the correct conclusion to draw from the assumptions is that $\mathfrak{p}$ is not in the support of the finite torsion module $\mathcal{O}_L/\mathcal{O}_K[\alpha]$.

Thank you. Since I haven't studied local concepts at all before, it will take me a while to interpret and digest your answer. But the gist of it should be the following? You are saying that the answer is "no", one doesn't imply the other in my question. And broadly, $\alpha'$ also has minimal polynomial separable mod $\mathfrak p$, and it holds that $\mathfrak p$ is not in the support of the module, whereas $\mathfrak p'$ is in the support. And I'll have to check up on this, but since $\mathfrak p'$ is in the support, it contains the annihilator, so [...] so $p$ divides the order?

I would very much appreciate extra details if possible. To be honest, I'm a bit lost. $\mathfrak p'$ is in the support because in particular we must have $r\alpha \in \mathcal O_K[\alpha']$ for all $r$ in the annihilator, implying $r\alpha=cu\alpha$ for some $c\in\mathcal O_K$, so $\mathfrak p'\ni cu= r$? Why is $\mathfrak p$ not in the support?
